# Is there an option to compare folders (with subfolders/subfiles) with Assertj given Path?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, assertj

I am interested in adding to my Assertions verification of folder(path). Because I want to keep my classes  homogeneous I am looking for a neat solution with Assertj. I am considering to just extract each path to list of files/folders and comparing Lists, but the method will become some/much more complex then.

Was not able to find something fitting so far, looking at usingComparator() method, unsure on how or whether I can.
The method looks something like this:

```
public void assertEquals(Path actual, Path expected) {
    Assertions.assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think, I got an answer to my own question: https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/504 :(

Comment: we have reopened the issue but we need to spike it before committing to adding such feature to AssertJ as it might be a substantial piece of work.